# Dealing with Real time variables and compensating the errors from adc

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, adc

I tried to implement real time systems using micro controllers and often used sensors/adc as input to monitor my surroundings so that i could adjust well with it.but how should one deal with the real time variables?. I have seen codes which implement **median filtering and low pass filters(in firmware code)** to the raw data obtained from sensor/adc.I have seen adc readings varying abruptly when taken continuously.

What is the best practice to avoid anomalies in sensor/adc readings such that  s/m will continue to work as expected.And how to fix the threshold and ranges of the variable?
I feel that real time variables must be carefully handled.
So How much effective is this median filtering and low pass filters than the direct raw data  processing?
Is there any better methods that effectively trade off b/w raw data acquisition time and processing time.

ok.
I am using pic18f  controller and using the adc channels of it as well and i am taking adc values continuously to monitor my system(Temperature controller). It shows slight variations in the adc conversions when i tried observing those values.
Then i heard about this median filtering and low pass filter techniques implemented in Embedded system for monitoring continuous**variables(Temperature)** in it.

The purpose of those techniques were to filter out the junk values as a result of EMI or any other external sources as far as my understanding.

So my point is :
Is it the only technique that embedded systems are using to get rid of absurd data they obtain..or there exists better techniques(lesser cycles).

Regards

Comment: It would take a book to answer your question.  In practice, the questions that you've asked are answered on a case-by-case basis.  Signals are different in different kinds of instruments.  Noises are different.  Objectives are different too.  You could ask a more specific question and tell what you are measuring and for what purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Digital filtering is a a huge topic that is very tough.

Of course you can try stuff that might work at the end, but that's not what I call "design".

For your particular problem, there is something important to understand: All digital filtering are applied math. Theses math are correct when (and only when) some assumptions are met. One of the most important one is the Nyquist criteria which basically says that none of the frequency content of the input signal should be higher than half the sampling rate.

For instance, if you plan to acquire at 100kHz (ADC at 100'000 samples/s), you must ensure that there is no content at frequencies higher than 50kHz in the analog signal at the ADC  input pin. And this is very important. If you don't ensure that (and we will see later how to do this) then you are not allowed to do the math of the signal processing theory. I don't say that you cannot do them but I said that it might be that your digital low pass filter will not behave as such or that you will see unexpected behaviors.

It might be that your sensor is bandwidth limited, then you know that you will never see any frequencies above a given threshold. Then you can enter the ADC directly (if the Nyquist criteria is met, or course). But if it's not the case, what you usually do to avoid this is to put an analog low pass filter at the input of your ADC with a cut off frequency much lower than the Nyquist frequency (half the sampling rate, in our example 50kHz). Why "much lower"? In fact you have to ensure that at the Nyquist frequency and above, your filter already has a strong attenuation. This filter is called an anti-aliasing filter.

For your particular problem: You can see that you may need an analog filter at the input of your ADC and you wanted to have some low pass filtering on your data. What I suggest, is to use the anti-aliasing filter to do your low pass filtering directly. That way, you don't need the software filtering at all. This will save a lot of computing cycles.

What would be the advantage to use a digital filter here? If you already need a low pass analog filter at the input: No real advantages, except that the filter will not by sensitive to component tolerances if done in software (is it a requirement here? not sure).

What I suggest: Put an analog low pass filter at the input of you ADC and you will not get any "absurd" data in your signal. (With the assumption that you don't pollute your signal between the low pass filter and the ADC and that your absurd data are not coming from some software bugs)